# prevent duplicate while merging redux array of objects with setState array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

First of all one general question that how to concat setState array with redux array? In my implementation, there is a configured list which is based on setState array of objects. Now, i have a location list which is based on redux array of objects. Now i am adding one item from location list to configured list using concat and saving the data. It is successfully saved but in merged list it is displaying 3 items (that redux array item 2 times).

But, i checked in console although it is showing correct result(2 items) but why it is displaying 3 items(redux item 2 times).

Component code:(getLocationData method where i did the concatenation part and calling that method in other component using callback ref and working fine)

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
               open:false,
               configuredList:[],
               retrievedList:[]
        };
       this.configLocation = this.configLocation.bind(this);
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.removeConfigLocation = this.removeConfigLocation.bind(this);
        this.mergedLocation = this.mergedLocation.bind(this);
    }

    togglePanel (e){
        this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
    }
    handleRemove(mruCode){
        this.props.removeLocation(mruCode)
     }
    handleClick (mruCode){
      this.props.addLocation(mruCode)
     }
     allLocations (){
       this.props.addAllLocation()
    }
    clearall (){
        this.props.removeAllLocation()
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if(this.props.locationData !=null && this.props.locationData!= undefined){
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
      }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || prevProps.locationData != this.props.locationData) && this.props.locationData != null && this.props.locationData != undefined) {
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
            this.mergedLocation();
        }
    }

    configLocation(locationData){
        let configuredList =[];
        if(locationData.locations.locationDetails != null && locationData.locations.locationDetails !=undefined ){
            locationData.locations.locationDetails.map(item=>{
                 let listitem ={...item};
                 configuredList.push(listitem);
            });
        }
        this.setState({configuredList},()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        }); 
    }

    removeConfigLocation(index){
        this.setState({
            configuredList:this.props.locationData.locations.locationDetails.filter((_,i)=>i!==index)
        },()=>{
            console.log(this.state.configuredList);
        });

    }


    mergedLocation(){
         if(this.props.conLocations != null && this.state.configuredList !=null){
             const{configuredList} = this.state;
             let retrievedList = configuredList;
             this.props.conLocations.forEach(loct => {
                 const locationAdded = retrievedList.find(_loct=>loct.mruCode=== loct.mruCode)
             });
          this.setState({
              retrievedList},()=>{
            console.log(this.state.retrievedList);
          });
         }  
    }

    getLocationData(){
        let saveableLocationlist = [];
        if(this.state.retrievedList != null){
            saveableLocationlist = retrievedList;
        }
        const locationData = {
            locationDetails : saveableLocationlist
        }
      return locationData;
    }



    render(){
        //const{configuredList} = this.state;
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return(
            <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading" onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)}>
              <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-6 panelHeadingLabel">
                     <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                     </div>
                        <div className="pull-right">
                        <span className="defaultHeaderTextColor">{this.state.configuredList.map((loc,index)=><span key={index}>{loc.mruCode} - {_labels[loc.division]} - {loc.country}</span>)}
                           <span onClick={(e)=>this.togglePanel(e)} className={this.state.open ? "collapse-chevronn" : "collapse-chevron"} aria-hidden="true"></span>
                   </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              {this.state.open?(
                        <div className="panel-body">
                             <div className="row grid-divider">
                             <div className="col-sm-6">
                             <div className="col-padding"><div className="pos-div"><h3>Locations List</h3><button style={{ display: this.props.location.length === this.props.conLocations.length ? "none" : "block" }} className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>{this.allLocations()}}>Add all locations</button></div><hr/>
                             {this.props.location.map((item,index)=>(
                             <div key={index}><div><b>{item.mruCode} - {_labels[item.division]} - {item.country}</b>{!this.props.conLocations.find(item2 => item.mruCode === item2.mruCode)&&(<div className="pull-right jd"><button style={{ display: this.state.configuredList.find(item3=> item.mruCode===item3.mruCode) ? "none" : "block" }} className="call-to-action" onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(item.mruCode)}}>Add Location</button></div>)}<hr/></div></div>))}
                            </div>
                             </div> 
                                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                                  <div className="col-padding">
                                  <div className="pos-div"><h3>Configured Location</h3><button className="allLargeBtn" onClick={()=>this.clearall()}>Remove all location</button></div><hr/>
              <div><table className="table"><tbody>{this.state.retrievedList.map((locc,index)=><tr key={index}><td><b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b></td><td className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></td></tr>)}
                    </tbody></table></div>

                                   </div>
                                  </div>
                                  </div> 
                    </div>):null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        location:state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations:state.locationRed.conLocations
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        loadData:()=>{dispatch(loadData())},
        addLocation:(mruCode)=>{dispatch(addLocation(mruCode))},
        addAllLocation:() =>{dispatch(addAllLocation())},
        removeLocation: (mruCode)=>{dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode))},
        removeAllLocation: () =>{dispatch(removeAllLocation())}
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps,null,{withRef:true})(NewLocationPanel);
```

**Jobs Component**(where i am calling getLocationData to save updated value of jobs...**It is saving the details properly**)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LocationPanel from '../panels/NewLocationPanel';

class JobsPanelComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            jobDetailJson: this.props.jobDetailJson

        };
this.setLocationPanelRef = cRef =>{this.locationPanel = cRef;};

}
componentWillUnmount() {
        this.clearStates();
        this.clearRefs();
        this.clearBindings();
    }
          clearStates() {

        this.state.jobDetailJson = null;
        }
        clearRefs(){
               this.locationPanel = null;
                   }
        clearBindings(){
               this.setLocationPanelRef = null;
                       }
        componentWillMount() {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = this.props.jobDetailJson;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = nextProps.jobDetailJson;
    }
     saveJobData(jobData){
      var locationData = null;
       if(some conditions){
        locationData = this.locationPanel.getWrappedInstance().getLocationData();
      }
    //more other lines not related to my mine
     }
      render(){
         var locationDataJson= null;
             if(this.state.jobDetailJson != null){
                     locationDataJson =this.state.jobDetailJson;
                   }
         return(<div className="panel-group" id="jobsPanelGroup">
               <LocationPanel ref={this.setLocationPanelRef} locationData ={locationDataJson} jobDetailJson={this.state.jobDetailJson} versionId={versionId} jobName={jobName} jobId={jobId} isForViewOnly={this.props.isForViewOnly} parentJobId={this.props.parentJobId} title="Location"/>
     //More coded lines for other things not related to my part
              );
         }


}
```

I am adding current output which is showing 3 results but it should show 2 results. How to prevent that.Please help me on this.[image]

Comment: Put console.log in getLocationData for configured list and conLocations. If it helps let me know so I can write an answer.

Comment: Yes for configuredList it is coming the first data values like pics. and for conLocations after adding single item it is showing 2nd data values. Yes i was rendering two array differently.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE #1:**

```
mergeLocationData(){
  let mergedList = [];    
  // you either have to setup initial state for conLocations in your reducer to `undefined` or to `null`. 
  if(this.props.conLocations !== undefined && this.state.configuredList !== null){
    const { configuredList } = this.state;
    const { conLocations } = this.props;
    mergedList = configuredList;

    this.props.conLocations.forEach(location => {
      const locationAdded = mergedList.find(_location => _location.mruCode === location.mruCode);
      if(!locationAdded){
        mergedList.push(location)
      }
    });
  }
    // instead of setting state, return the mergedList
    return mergedList; //[ always an array of elements ]
}
```

And then, at the render method: instead of getting the list from the state, we just invoke the function.

```
<thead>
  {
    this.mergeLocationData().map((locc,index)=> (
      <tr key={index}>
        <th>
          <b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b>
        </th>
        <th className="text-right">
          <img
            alt="DeleteIcon"
            onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}}
            className="deleteIconStyle"
            src="img/delete_large_active.png" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    )
  }
</thead>
```

---

There is nothing wrong with the code, I suppose it's correctly working, but, it's the logic that is not right, you are rendering both of the arrays in your render, you are not using the function `getLocationData` anyware in your component, eventhough, `concat` won't solve the problem.

You can do the following steps to fix the logic.
- Fix the logic of `getLocationData`:

```
mergeLocationData(){      
  // you either have to setup initial state for conLocations in your reducer to `undefined` or to `null`. 
  if(this.props.conLocations !== undefined && this.state.configuredList !== null){
    const { configuredList } = this.state;
    const { conLocations } = this.props;
    let mergedList = configuredList;

    this.props.conLocations.forEach(location => {
      const locationAdded = mergedList.find(_location => _location.mruCode === location.mruCode);
    });

    this.setState({
        mergedList
    });
  }
}
```

- Use the function as a callback to your fetch request, supposibly in  `componentDidMount` after loading the data correctly.
- Render the new `Array` of `mergedList` which should be in your state by now, and don't forget to add `mergedList: []` to your state.
  Basically you need to replace the two maps that render location elements in your render with that.

```
    <thead>
      {
        this.state.mergedList.map((locc,index)=> (
          <tr key={index}>
            <th>
              <b>{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</b>
            </th>
            <th className="text-right">
              <img
                alt="DeleteIcon"
                onClick={()=>{this.removeConfigLocation(index)}}
                className="deleteIconStyle"
                src="img/delete_large_active.png" />
            </th>
          </tr>
        )
      }
    </thead>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes that is the way i was searching. But, one question while adding location into that . locationAdded?? how to use that ? I am just confused on this part

Comment: if you mean while merging it, this is the bit where we check for the existance of an object and depending on it we push, or not `mergedList.find(_location => _location.mruCode === location.mruCode);`

Comment: I have edited my question in where i am using that getLocationData. I am saving the  data into locationData and calling that method into that Jobs Component. It is saving properly. Now how to do that in your mergedLocationData () part. Will you please add this part too in your code? so i can edit and test that

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is the way i understood after so many trials. Just show me how to configure the save locationData part in mergedLocationData() as per your answer

Comment: If you save the data in the store, then invoke the merge function again, things should be ok.

Comment: what if i will  create one method like yours and send mergedList to getLocationData and calling it to job component like i did previously. I think it will work. Because problem was two different list rendering. What will you say? It will work

Comment: I will work, and I will update the answer to match with the following, If you are handling the data save in another component and it's hard to invoke the function after the save event, the updated answer will still do the job, as when you update the store, the component will re-render, and then we evaluate the new mergedList in the `render()` method without the usage of `setState()`, and that is the cheapest solution, another solution is to make mergedList in your redux store with the same functionality..

Comment: I have updated my code as you replied. Now, mergedlist is showing nothing.

Comment: I have updated the code, but, I can't find a scenario that it will not render elements unless this: `this.props.conLocations !== undefined && this.state.configuredList !== null` returns false.